# Apache user [www-data] within a docker container can't write into a mounted volume

Tags: php, docker, permissions

Even though permissions look fine within the container:

`drwxrwxr-x  12 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  5 16:04 app`

I'm getting a permission denied error when Apache is trying to write anything into that directory.

FYI: /app is mounted from the host machine like this:

`/var/www/myApp:/app`

> Error is
>
> \Exception\ErrorException: file_put_contents(/app/docker.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /app/src/Business/ExpediteGround/LHRates/Fetch.php:13

Comment: Try adding this to your PHP dockerfile `RUN usermod -a -G staff www-data` as per my lamp stack here https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp/blob/master/build/php/Dockerfile#L7

Comment: Is it the _same_ `www-data` user?  The numeric user ID, not the name, is what actually matters.  It’s also relevant if you’ve enabled user namespace remapping on Docker, or if you’re on a non-Linux host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn't enable anything for user remapping, as for the user ID they both show 33 inside or outside the container (running Ubuntu 16). FYI I got that ID [33] running id -u www-data in the host AND within the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue everyone, Apache user was just fine (www-data) but I'm using fpm inside the container to compile the php code and it was running with a different user so that was the cause; switched the pool to run as www-data as I'm used to and it worked!